# Sendgrid integration with Dynamics CRM

Tags: sendgrid

Can sendgrid **Design & Code Editor**(“what you see is what you get”-WYSIWYG) connect to dynamics CRM ,to send emails to a bunch of people in a particular event?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you ca do so, I haven't worked with Sengrid, but with something similar .... 
- Create your templates on your Sendgrid account
- Create a Workflow Activity/Plugin that will generate an API call giving the needed specifications, inform yourself [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_getting_started.html).